# Mocking OpenGL ES Library so c++ project builds

Tags: c++, mocking, opengl-es

I've been trying to mock the OpenGL ES just enough so my project will build, but I've been having some issues. When I try to build my project I get a bunch of errors such as:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _screen_get_display_property_iv referenced in function...
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__glBindBuffer@8
```

I'm looking for help starting the mock as I've tried a bunch of different approaches but continue to get errors like "redefinition of dllimport function not allowed". If someone could show me the format in which to start writing the header/class file for the mock that'd be much appreciated as I have little experience mocking a C library.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'd use a GL loader/generator like [glad](https://gen.glad.sh/).

The idea behind such a wrapper is to load the functions dynamically (at runtime) via `eglGetProcAddress` or any similar function provided by the display/window lib you prefer to use.